Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1: google is not defined date?
Our service that sends push notifications (via FCM) to Android devices stopped working. After digging some docs, we found the cause is:

Sending messages (including upstream messages) with those APIs was
deprecated on June 20, 2023, and shutdown begins on July 22, 2024
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

I tried to fix the function that delivers FCM message from:
function sendPaidNotificationMessage(to, transactionID, mobileNumber, callback) {
    unirest.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send').headers({
        'Authorization': config.get('googleNotificationAuth'),
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }).proxy('http://xxxxxxxx:xxxx').send({
        'to': to,
        'priority': 'high',
        'restricted_package_name': config.get('googlePkgName'),
        'notification': {
            'title': 'Hello. Invoice # ' + transactionID + ' has been paid. Thank you.'
        },
        'data': {
            'transactionID': transactionID,
            'mobileNumber': mobileNumber
        }
    }).end(function(responseFCM) {
        callback(responseFCM);
    });
}

into this:
function sendPaidNotificationMessage(to, transactionID, mobileNumber, callback) {
    var myAccessToken = getAccessToken()
    unirest.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/messages:send').headers({
        'Authorization': myAccessToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }).proxy('http://xxxxxxxx:xxxx').send({
        'to': to,
        'priority': 'high',
        'restricted_package_name': config.get('googlePkgName'),
        'notification': {
            'title': 'Hello. Invoice # ' + transactionID + ' has been paid. Thank you.'
        },
        'data': {
            'transactionID': transactionID,
            'mobileNumber': mobileNumber
        }
    }).end(function(responseFCM) {
        callback(responseFCM);
    });
}

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#node.js_1
function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const key = require('./service-account.json');
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
}

Running the service (on FreeBSD 13.2, Node 18.16.0) gives this error:

error: uncaughtException: google is not defined date=Tue Sep 17 2024
00:33:45 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time), pid=47520, uid=0,
gid=0, cwd=/storage/app/platform_xxxx/xxxx.xxxx.notification,
execPath=/usr/local/bin/node, version=v18.16.0,
argv=[/usr/local/bin/node,
/storage/app/platform_xxxx/xxxx.xxxx.notification/server.js],
rss=129961984, heapTotal=54124544, heapUsed=49451000,
external=18824867, arrayBuffers=17895641, loadavg=[0.1279296875,
0.3095703125, 0.2421875], uptime=8452173, trace=[column=22, file=/storage/app/platform_xxxx/xxxxs.xxxx.xxxx/server.js,
function=null, line=1659, method=null, native=false, column=null,
file=null, function=new Promise, line=null, method=null, native=false,
column=9, file=/storage/app/platform_xxxx/xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/server.js,
function=getAccessToken, line=1657, method=null, native=false,
column=22, file=/storage/app/platform_xxxx/xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/server.js,

By looking at the error, I guess a dependency is missing: perhaps google-auth-library-nodejs? So I installed it:
npm install google-auth-library

Sadly the same error still happens. What's wrong here?

Have you npm install'd googleapis?

@DazWilkin. Just did it. Hmm doesn't work. Still meet the same error  error: uncaughtException: google is not defined ...

Ah silly me. Forgot to add this line on the top: const { google } = require('googleapis');. At least the uncaugException is solved.
